# How to skip the first three elements in first instance of loop

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

How can I achieve this using python

```
for season in seasons:
    print('Season:',season)
    season_response = requests.get(season, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    season_content = season_response.content
    season_doc = html.fromstring(season_content)
    dates = [base + date for date in season_doc.xpath('//*[@id="bloccontenu"]//div[@class="select-container select-game"]/select/option/@value')]
    for date in dates:
        print(date)
        # print dates
        # exclude the first three dates of only the first instance of loop
```

How can I print excluding the first three dates of the first season, but print all the other dates of every other season?

for example, season 1 has 6 dates, season 2 has 5 dates : 
I expect such an output, where the first 3 dates of season 1 are excluded :

```
Season: season 1  
date4
date5
date6
Season: season 2
date1
date2
date3
date4
date5
```

Comment: Can you post a (simplified, if necessary) version of the first two elements in `seasons`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for season in seasons:
    print('Season:',season)
    season_response = requests.get(season, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    season_content = season_response.content
    season_doc = html.fromstring(season_content)
    dates = [base + date for date in season_doc.xpath('//*[@id="bloccontenu"]//div[@class="select-container select-game"]/select/option/@value')]

    if season == seasons[0]:
        dates = dates[3:]

    for date in dates:
        print(date)
```

When the season is equal to season 1, discard the first 3 dates?

Comment: Thanks @Juke. Your answer actually gave me an idea of what to do. 
    if season == seasons[0]:
        dates = dates[3:]